# How To Draw Multiple Polygons based on a JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps, servlets

I'm trying to draw multiple polygons using a JSON Array. Here's my current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var drawingManager;
        var elements;

        //Overlays
        var polygons = [];
        var polylines = [];
        //JSON String turned into array
        var newPolygons = '<%=request.getAttribute("polygons")%>';
        var editedPolygons = JSON.parse(newPolygons);

        function initialize() {
            //Map
            var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.5667, 120.9927),
                zoom: 18,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

            //Drawing Manager
            var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                    drawingModes: [
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                        google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
                    ]
                }
            });
            drawingManager.setMap(map);

            //Triggers
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
                drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
                var polypath = polygon.getPath().getArray();
                polygons.push(polypath);
            }); 
            //Create the Polygons
             var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: editedPolygons,
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35

            });
        }
        //Sends to Servlet
        function sendElements() {
            var elementsJSON = JSON.stringify(polygons);               
            window.location.assign("LoadNextPage?polygons=" + elementsJSON);
        }
    </script>
```

I send the elementsJSON to another page by using a servlet, I edit it, then I send it back to the main page through another servlet and turn it back into an array using JSON.parse. But the main page doesn't show the polygons no matter what I do. How do I do it?

Here is an example of what the newPolygons JSON String looks like:

```
[[{"H":14.56754606924714,"L":120.99225461483002},{"H":14.567213783453319,"L":120.9916752576828},{"H":14.566736121747363,"L":120.99207758903503}],[{"H":14.566383066777853,"L":120.99221169948578},{"H":14.566325954891425,"L":120.99138557910919},{"H":14.565635419093956,"L":120.9915840625763}]]
```

But I still use JSON.parse on that.

Here is the code I use for the servlet that leads to the second page:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String elementsJSON = (String) request.getParameter("polygons");

    request.setAttribute("polygons", elementsJSON);
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatch = context.getRequestDispatcher("/second-pageAgain.jsp");

    dispatch.forward(request, response);

}
```

Here is the code for the second page

```
<script>
        var elementsJSON = '<%=request.getAttribute("polygons")%>';
        var elements;
        function init(){ 
          document.getElementById('savedata').value = elementsJSON;
        }
        function saveChanges(){
            elements = document.getElementById('savedata').value;
            alert(elements);
            window.location.assign("LoadMaps?polygons=" + elements);
        }
    </script>
```

And here is the code for the servlet I use to go back to the main page with the edited coordinates.

```
 protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String elements = (String) request.getParameter("polygons");
    System.out.println(elements);
    request.setAttribute("polygons", elements);
    ServletContext context = getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher dispatch = context.getRequestDispatcher("/maps2Again.jsp");
    dispatch.forward(request, response);
}
```

I'm trying to draw the polygons, that I edited in the second page, on the map but I can't seem to make it appear.

Comment: Looks like you are using undocumented properties of the API ("H", "L").  Don't do that, those names can and do change with every release of the API (approximately every 3 months)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
for (var i = 0; i < editedPolygons.length; i++) {
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: editedPolygons[i],
        map: map
    });
}
```

**Note:** I changed your JSON from "H" to "lat", "L" to "lng" to make it [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral) objects so it would be portable across API releases.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6xc37s6m/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var editedPolygons = [
  [{
    "lat": 14.56754606924714,
    "lng": 120.99225461483002
  }, {
    "lat": 14.567213783453319,
    "lng": 120.9916752576828
  }, {
    "lat": 14.566736121747363,
    "lng": 120.99207758903503
  }],
  [{
    "lat": 14.566383066777853,
    "lng": 120.99221169948578
  }, {
    "lat": 14.566325954891425,
    "lng": 120.99138557910919
  }, {
    "lat": 14.565635419093956,
    "lng": 120.9915840625763
  }]
];

var map;
var drawingManager;
var elements;

//Overlays
var polygons = [];
var polylines = [];
//JSON String turned into array
// var newPolygons = '<%=request.getAttribute("polygons")%>';
// var editedPolygons = JSON.parse(newPolygons);

function initialize() {
    //Map
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.5667, 120.9927),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    for (var i = 0; i < editedPolygons.length; i++) {
      var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: editedPolygons[i],
        map: map
      });
    }
    //Drawing Manager
    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
      drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
      drawingControl: true,
      drawingControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
        drawingModes: [
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
          google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE
        ]
      }
    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    //Triggers
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
      drawingManager.setDrawingMode(null);
      var polypath = polygon.getPath().getArray();
      polygons.push(polypath);
    });
    //Create the Polygons
    var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: editedPolygons,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 3,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35

    });
  }
  //Sends to Servlet

function sendElements() {
  var elementsJSON = JSON.stringify(polygons);
  window.location.assign("LoadNextPage?polygons=" + elementsJSON);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=drawing&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="googleMap"></div>
```